# Gradle flywayMigrate gives out of memory exception

Tags: java, gradle, flyway

I was trying to set up database migrations using flyway and gradle. The task fails with the following error

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:233)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:117)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(FileCopyUtils.java:68)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.scanner.classpath.ClassPathResource.loadAsBytes(ClassPathResource.java:100)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.extractMigrationInfo(SqlMigrationResolver.java:140)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:112)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:41)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.collectMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:126)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.doFindAvailableMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:108)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:94)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:42)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:96)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.doInTransaction(DbValidate.java:136)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.doInTransaction(DbValidate.java:131)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:131)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1014)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$300(Flyway.java:52)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:925)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:919)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1320)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:919)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$migrate$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask.run(FlywayMigrateTask.groovy:30)
        at org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask$run.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.flywaydb.gradle.task.AbstractFlywayTask.runTask(AbstractFlywayTask.groovy:75)
```

I tried the following

```
echo $GRADLE_OPTS
-Xmx2048m

echo $JAVA_OPTS
-Xmx2048m
```

Added some settings to the gradle properties too:

```
cat ~/.gradle/gradle.properties 
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
```

That did not help, Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
    }
}


plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "4.0.3"
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb'
    user = 'root'
    password = 'abc!23'
    schemas = ['mydb']
    baselineVersion = 1
    baselineDescription = "Baselining myDB Schema"
}
```

Basically I was using a very old version of FlyWay that has caused the Java Heap Space - My Bad.
This build script above can be a resource for any one who want to perform DB Migrations using FlyWay on MYSQL.